# Indexing to access elements of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, sparse-matrix

In the example below, I am creating idxL and I want to loop through its elements to carry out other operations. I'm trying to understand why `idxL[0][0]` returns `[[ True False False False False]]` instead of returning just `True`. `idxL.item(0)` seems to work. I think I could loop through the entire number of items in idxL using it. However, for some reason, I think it would not be as efficient when I start handling bigger arrays.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
a=['foo','panda','donkey','bird','egg']
b='foo'
idxL=csr_matrix((1,5), dtype=bool)
idxTemp=np.array(list(map(lambda x: x in b, a)))
idxL = idxL + idxTemp
print(idxL[0][0])
print(idxL.item(0))
```

Comment: `idxL[0,0]` is the correct way for a sparse matrix, and preferred even for numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj It doesn't seem to work, though. I am wondering why.

Comment: What doesn't work?  what does it do? Looping on a sparse matrix is inefficient, worse than loping on a dense array.  Stick with list or dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [193]: from scipy import sparse                                              
In [194]: a=['foo','panda','donkey','bird','egg'] 
     ...: b='foo' 
     ...: idxL=sparse.csr_matrix((1,5), dtype=bool) 
     ...: idxTemp=np.array(list(map(lambda x: x in b, a)))
```

The sparse matrix:

```
In [195]: idxL                                                                  
Out[195]: 
<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [196]: idxL.A                                                                
Out[196]: array([[False, False, False, False, False]])
```

the dense array; note that it is 1d

```
In [197]: idxTemp                                                               
Out[197]: array([ True, False, False, False, False])
```

Indexing the sparse matrix:

```
In [198]: idxL[0,0]                                                             
Out[198]: False
```

The addition - it is a dense matrix now:

```
In [199]: idxLL = idxL + idxTemp                                                
In [200]: idxLL                                                                 
Out[200]: matrix([[ True, False, False, False, False]])
In [201]: idxLL[0,0]                                                            
Out[201]: True
```

`[0]` of a matrix selects the first row, but the result will still be 2d.  `[0][0]` indexing doesn't help.  This style of indexing works with 2d `ndarray`, but the `[0,0]` is generally better.

```
In [202]: idxLL[0]                                                              
Out[202]: matrix([[ True, False, False, False, False]])
In [203]: idxTemp[0]                                                            
Out[203]: True
```

### edit

We can make a sparse matrix from `idxTemp` directly:

```
In [257]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(idxTemp)                                        
In [258]: M                                                                     
Out[258]: 
<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [259]: M.A                                                                   
Out[259]: array([[ True, False, False, False, False]])
In [260]: print(M)                                                              
  (0, 0)    True
```

There's no need to add it to `idxL`.  It could be added:

```
In [261]: idxL+M                                                                
Out[261]: 
<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I wouldn't recommend building a spare matrix by adding matrices.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening becasue idxL is not np.array but [np.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).
to turn this to numpy array refer to attribute 'A' which return the np.array.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
a=['foo','panda','donkey','bird','egg']
b='foo'
idxL=csr_matrix((1,5), dtype=bool)
idxL.todense()
idxTemp=np.array(list(map(lambda x: x in b, a)))
idxL = idxL + idxTemp
print(idxL.A[0][0])
print(idxL.item(0))

output:
True
True
```

Edit: if you want to stay with sparse you should change your original code to

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
a=['foo','panda','donkey','bird','egg']
b='foo'
idxL=csr_matrix((1,5), dtype=bool)
idxL.todense()
idxTemp=csr_matrix(list(map(lambda x: x in b, a)))
idxL = idxL + idxTemp
print(idxL[0][0])
```

Now idxL is still csr_matrix and honors the [] indexing.

Comment: What if I don't want to convert idxL to a dense matrix to save memory?

Comment: So use the item(). This is the np.matrix api.

Comment: BTW. the idxL in the print is not sparse anymore because the addition. It is casted to np.matrix

Comment: What does `idxL[0,0]` do?